# Why are my column headers combined when importing csv to MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, csv, mysql-workbench

When I try to upload my csv, my headers get combined, so it says I only have 4 whereas there are 10. When I open my csv in excel, the categories are properly in their 10 respective columns. I'm using the import wizard. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You obviously use the wrong separator (space) while the correct one would be a comma. This can be set as option in the import wizard.